# Publish ASP.NET Core to IIS with GITLAB CI/CD

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab-ci

I can run the web application by using `dotnet run` on the `.gitlab-ci.yml` script.

```
stages:
    - build
build:
    stage: build
    before_script:
        - 'dotnet restore'
    script:
        - echo "Building the My Application"
        - "dotnet publish Eitms.Decoder.sln -c release"
        - "cd C:\\MyFolderContaints\\Eitms.Decoder.Backend"
        - "dotnet run"
    only:
        - release
```

But how I can publish into the IIS? anyone can show the step?

Thanks

## UPDATE

After view the script from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311770/dotnet-publish-with-gitlab-ci-for-dummies), still not success yet. Did I do something wrong here?

```
stages:
    - build    
    - deploy
build:
    stage: build
    before_script:
        - 'dotnet restore'
    script:
        - echo "Building the app"
        - "dotnet publish Eitms.Decoder.sln -c release"
    artifacts:
        untracked: true
    only:
        - release

deploy_staging:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Deploy to IIS"
        - "dotnet publish Eitms.Decoder.Backend\\Eitms.Decoder.Backend.csproj -c release -o C:\\Secret Path\\PRODUCTION\\Secret Project"
    dependencies:
        - build
    only:
        - release
```

Comment: i'm currently working in something like this and found strange that nobody is helping :( let me get back to you soon; did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes I already found the solution. I will update you soon

Comment: great! thanks @azri-zacaria

Answer (score 4):

I don't know is it still actual or not and also i never used GitLab CI
but looking on provided scripts i think you need just to copy (using CMD commands like xcopy) files into IIS folder after publish
like when you want to do same using CMD .bat file

Steps

1. publish project
2. stop appPool
3. copy files
4. start appPool

e.g (just for example)

```
 dotnet publish "Eitms.Decoder.Backend\\Eitms.Decoder.Backend.csproj" -c release -o "C:\\Secret Path\\PRODUCTION\\Secret Project"
 appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:"Secret Project APP POOL"
 xcopy "C:\\Secret Path\\PRODUCTION\\Secret Project" "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Secret Project" /s /e
 appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:"Secret Project APP POOL"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement, and @Simon response helped me a lot. But when trying to apply it, I was confronted to some other problems that I have handled with an improved script

```
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'dotnet publish WebProjectFolder\\WebProject.csproj -c release -o E:\\TemporaryLocation'
    #I used powershell to stop the apppool. 
    #I also added a test to verify that the apppool is already Started. (If you try to stop a stopped apppool your job will fail)
    - 'if ((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name pointeuse).Value -eq "Started") { Stop-WebAppPool -Name pointeuse }' 
    # I used /exclude so I doesn't copy config files (in my case it was web.config and appsettings.json)
    # These config files already exists under my IIS because they contains specific configuration (So I copied them manually once because they do not change)
    # deployignore.txt is a file that I added to the root of my solution (next to SolutionName.sln). It contains the config files that I don't want to copy (In my case it contains 2 lines web.config and appsettings.json)
    # E:\\DeployLocation is the folder where your IIS site points to
    - 'xcopy /s /e /y /exclude:deployignore.txt E:\\TemporaryLocation E:\\DeployLocation'
    # Added the sleep because the app pool couldn't be started (maybe I can lower the sleep delay)
    - sleep 10
    - 'Start-WebAppPool -Name pointeuse'
  only:
    - master
```

Real thanks Simon.